# Vim: Indent current (blank) line and insert

Tags: vim, indentation

Say I have the current text in the buffer, where `_` marks the cursor

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");

_
}
```

I have `indentexpr` on (though a solution with `cindent` or `autoindent` will probably work, too).

How do I begin inserting so my cursor is placed at the appropriate column to follow the indention rules, i.e.:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");

    _
}
```

Currently I find myself using `ddO` often (or `ddo` at the end of the buffer), but it seems there should be a better way.  Using `==` or even `>>` or `v>` do not seem to work because the line is blank.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try going back into normal mode and typing `S`

Comment: Yes!  That was it!  Thanks a lot.  (I was already in normal mode; in insert mode I sometimes spam <CTRL-T>.)

Comment: Looking at `:help S`, `cc` does the same thing.  (I never use `cc`, so that's probably why I didn't even consider using that (nor `S`, which I never even knew about).)

Answer (score 8):

If I'm on a blank line, but at the wrong insertion point, I tend to use `CTRL-f` (while in insert mode) to indent to the correct place.

This is useful when I've hit `ESC` to get out of insert mode, and I've then lost the proper indentation. Hitting `i` followed by `CTRL-f` does the trick.

Comment: `==` does that, but I didn't know I could do `==` in insert mode.

Comment: @strager what's do you mean for `==` could do in insert mode?  It seems doesn't work for me.