# Auto indenting fails when using the "cc", "S", or "]p" commands on a blank line in Vim

Tags: vim, indentation

If I try `cc` or `S` when the cursor (`|` below) is in the following
position:

```
public function blah()
{
    var i = 0;
|
    i++
    return i;
}
```

It stays in the first column instead of moving under the letter `v` in `var`. Pasting with `]p` also pastes starting from column 1.

My setup (in MacVim) is: `autoindent`, `smartindent`, `nocindent`, and `indentexpr=`, if that helps.

According to the following SO questions, correct indentation should be possible:

- [Vim: Smart indent when entering insert mode on blank line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003393/vim-smart-indent-when-entering-insert-mode-on-blank-line)
- [Vim: Indent current (blank) line and insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718026/vim-indent-current-blank-line-and-insert)
- [Autoindent in vim always empty the line if there are only whitespace in it, can I change that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000842/autoindent-in-vim-always-empty-the-line-if-there-are-only-whitespace-in-it-can-i)

In the last post, [@trVoldemort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667027/trvoldemort) had the same issue (see the comments to the second answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on `cindent`...

```
:set cindent
```

This works for indenting with "cc" and "S", as long as the language has similar indentation to C (or support for cindent).

With this, the smart-indent paste (`]p`) still doesn't work on an empty line, however.  For that, remap `]p` as follows:

```
:nnoremap ]p oX<Esc>]pk"_dd
```

This will create a new line at the correct indentation before doing the re-indent paste. Then it goes back and deletes that line, making sure not to overwrite the default buffer.

You can also remap the alternative versions of the smart-indent paste:

```
:nnoremap ]P OX<Esc>]pk"_dd
:vnoremap ]p "_xkoX<Esc>]pk"_dd
:vnoremap ]P "_xkoX<Esc>]pk"_dd
```

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

```
                            *cc*
["x]cc          Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
                insert |linewise|.  If 'autoindent' is on, preserve
                the indent of the first line.

                            *S*
["x]S           Delete [count] lines [into register x] and start
                insert.  Synonym for "cc" |linewise|.
```

Since the line you are deleting has no indent, that indent is preserved.
If you insert spaces in that line, so that <kbd>$</kbd> puts your cursor here:

```
public function blah() {
    var i = 0;
    |
    i++
    return i;
}
```

then press <kbd>0</kbd> to go back to the first column, and finally press <kbd>S</kbd>, you'll get the desired result.

I realize this only explains the current behavior but does not directly solve your problem, but I am unsure of a clean way to solve your issue.  I'd be inclined to suggested doing a mapping like this:

```
:nnoremap cc ddko
:nnoremap S ddko
```

These <kbd>dd</kbd> delete the current line, <kbd>k</kbd> move up to the previous line, <kbd>o</kbd> open input on the following line (using smartindent to supply the indentation).

Comment: Couldn't be better explained!

Comment: I like your straightforward solution; however, it only works if the previous line is non-empty.  Also, I think it is autoindent, but one of the options I am using will remove the spaces you add after exiting the line (or insert mode) unless you type some non-whitespace characters in the line.

Comment: I've removed the `$` from your answer (in `ddk$o`) as there's no need for it. `o` doesn't care where in the line you are.

Comment: @Chris: Quite right.  Just a habit of mine, I guess.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

One can explicitly auto-indent lines before applying the `cc`, `S`, or
`]p` Normal-mode command, as shown in the following mappings.

```
:nnoremap <leader>cc i.<esc>==S
:nnoremap <leader>]p ]p`[v`]=
```

Generally speaking, the effect of the `=` and `==` commands is not
exactly the same as the effect of the `autoindent` option has on
the `cc` or `]p` commands (especially in case of a custom `equalprg`),
but resulting behavior seems to, nevertheless, match your description.

Comment: @ib: it can be nicer to use `<Esc>` rather than the escaped `^[` version.

Comment: @Chris:  You are right!  I have a habit of typing special symbols literally using `Ctrl`+`V`, and sometimes I forget that in mappings it is possible to use angle brackets expansion.

Comment: @ib: I'm in the same boat.  I just recently decided to reform slightly. It won't last long, though, I dare say.

Answer (score 0):

When I use `:filetype indent on`, pressing <kbd>cc</kbd> on that line indents it properly.

Comment: Not sure why, but this doesn't work for me still. What are your settings for autoindent, smartindent, cindent, and indentexpr?

Comment: With every setting at its default and `cindent` turned on, I get proper indentation.

Comment: I think it is `cindent` that is fixing it.